# Put a date variable in quotes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have declared a variable that is getting date from an output activity.
vGetDate= 2021-03-20 and want to use this value in my query to fetch the record after that date. eg: (`Select * from ABC where UpdatedDate > vGetDate`) . I want to put single quotes to date in order to make it work properly.

Below is my code

```
declare @date1 varchar(20) = activity.output i.e will return o/p in this format(without quotes) : 2021-03-22

select *
from abc
where format([UpdatedDtTm],'yyyy-MM-dd') > cast(@date1 as datetime).
```

I am using this but since date1 variable has date without quotes , thats why this where condition is not working fine.

Comment: Which database are you actually using? `[UpdateDtTm]` looks like SQL-Server syntax, but that's not any of your tags.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: So why can't you put quotes? `activity.output('2021-03-22')`

Comment: the where clause predicate is comparing a varchar (returned by format) to a datetime (returned by cast) - this is not good. Also what happend to `@date1` did it become `@LastPaymentProcessedDT` ?

Comment: That code looks very product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Paul, its like this 
where format([UpdatedDtTm],'yyyy-MM-dd')>cast(@date1 as datetime).

Comment: Barmar, because i am geeting this value as an output from a different job

Comment: `declare @date1 varchar(20) = 2021-03-22` will set the variable to `'1996'`

Comment: Why don't you pass in a parameter properly? How are you triggering this batch, can you pass it in from there?

Comment: Further this question appears to be a duplicate of your previous question. You should not ask the same question again. The reason you're not getting satisfactory answers to this question is that its very unclear what you are asking. You only normally need quotes when you manually assign a date to a variable, not when you assign it in code. And you normally compare a date as a date, not a string. We need a [mre] in order to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Implied data conversions inside a where clause can be a significant performance and/or reliability issue and should be avoided.

As I don't know anything about the `activity.output(2021-03-22)` or why you cannot use `activity.output('2021-03-22')` let's try to consider a simplified case. On the assumption that the column [UpdatedDtTm] is indeed a datetime column, then you can compare that column to a datetime variable without needing format() or cast(), like this:

```
declare @Date1 datetime = '20210322'
select * from abc 
where [UpdatedDtTm] > @Date1
```

Keep in mind that  any date related data types are NOT stored "in a format" they are actually numeric and any format that we use to understand the date or time is applied rather like typing 44279 into an Excel cell and then formatting it to a date which displays as 2021-03-24 (if your default date format is yyyy-mm-dd). It's not exactly the same in SQL Server but quite similar.

I am ignoring `activity.output` but assuming it is a string. Likewise I am assuming [UpdatedDtTm]  is a datetime column.

```
declare @Date1 datetime = try_cast(activity.output as datetime)
select * from abc 
where [UpdatedDtTm] > @Date1
```

or

```
declare @Date1 datetime = try_convert(datetime,activity.output,121)
select * from abc 
where [UpdatedDtTm] > @Date1
```

Note that `try_cast` or `try_convert` will not fail if the activity.output isn't a valid date but they will return NULL in such cases and your query will return no rows.

Once you have passed the value into @Date1 then you just compare datetime column to datetime variable. Try to ignore anything to do with "format"

Comment: its the o/p from Lookup Activity in Azure  which is not in quotes and  I have written a script that is utilizing the o/p . I want to put the quotes dynamically.

Comment: I don't believe you need quotes but I'm not familiar with `o/p` or `activity.output` so you are explaining it with terms that have no meaning to me. If `activity.output` returns a string, convert that into a datetime using `TRY_CAST( activity.output-goes-here as datetime)`

Comment: Just ignore that activity.output. Consider a variable having dates without quotes and you want to put the quotes in where condition otherwise it will pick all the data present in table.

Comment: seriously you do not need quotes in the where clause IF the variable is datetime and the [UpdatedDtTm] is a datetime column (not varchar)

Comment: I declared the variable as datetime and run the query

declare @date1 datetime = 2021-03-22
select date1 from abc;
 
its returning o/p as : 1905-06-20 00:00:00.000
That means its not working

Comment: *what is the data type of the column?* Honestly its really hard to help without absolute facts. I need the actual data type of the column NOT an opinion on what the data looks like

Comment: Its datetime datatype

Comment: you see that date because `2021-03-22` is 1996 and assigning an integer to a datetime will be converted as number of days since start of 20th Century (`DATEADD(DAY,1996,'1900-01-01')`). You should paramterise the SQL and pass it as a parameter value not concatenate it into the query

Comment: Ha! Interesting. If indeed it is being considered as `(2021 - 03 - 22 = 1996)` then that variable needs to be treated as varchar first, then converted to datetime.  Something like `try_cast(cast(activity.output as varchar) as datetime)`

Comment: thats also not working, its giving the same output 1905-06-20 00:00:00.000

Comment: Supply DDL, sample data and expected results. Add it to your question.